# Free & Paid iPhone app: Would I need two different provisioning profiles?

Tags: iphone, bundle

I'm a little confused about making Free (lite) and Paid (full) version of an iPhone app.

The reason I ask is because I'd like to have two versions for my app: a Free ad supported version and a Paid version, and I'd like to accomplish that with two different targets. Since they will be two different apps in the App Store, my understanding is they need two different Bundle IDs, right?.

1. Would I need two different Bundle ID’s for each target?
2. Would I need two different Info.plists for each target if I did
   this, or can I use the same Info.plist?
3. Would I need two different development/distribution provisioning
   profiles for each target, or can I use only one?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 bundle IDs.

You can use the same info.plist

You need two provisioning profiles, since that is the one that allows running the program, and apple requires to be different for each app.

Comment: What about launch icons?  Do they have to be different too?